# Count distinct with activerecord ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The table `Visit` contains the column `extra` which is written this way `user:xxx login:yyy` (string type).

I want to determine all the number of **distinct passwords** (after the word `login`). I wrote this ActiveRecord query in my controller.

```
Visit.select(:extra).where('extra LIKE ?', "%login%").distinct.count
```

This query will give me a result of distinct `extra` which contains the word `login` not the password (`yyy` in this example). I want to do the same but for all the strings (passwords) after the word `login`.

Is there any solution to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to achieve this.

```
Visit.select("SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra, ':', -1)").where('extra LIKE ?', "%login%").distinct.count
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives me wrong a result. For example, if `user:xxx login:yyy` and `user:xxx login:zzz`, the result will be always 1 not 2 even the passwords are different!

Comment: This is the idea but you have to change `1` by `-1` in `SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra, ':', 1)` to have the correct answer (to extract only the password because 1 gives as a result `user`). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @media - Thanks! Slipped out of mind that user is also there. I only considered `login`.

Comment: An alternative syntax for the same result: `Visit.where('extra LIKE ?', "%login%").distinct.count("SUBSTRING_INDEX(extra, ':', -1)")`